# Get exact location of an function definition in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can we get exact location of an predefined function in CodeIgniter to make some custom changes?

Comment: It's not a good idea to edit the base files of your framework, since when you upgrade, you'll have to re-apply your changes. Good frameworks will allow you to extend its core classes, and set the new ones up in a factory configuration.

Comment: Leading on from what @halfer said CodeIgniter provides mechanisms to extend core classes and hooking into the the pipeline as detailed on the following pages: 

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: I am not saying it is compulsory to edit the base files and there is nothing bad in editing them coz thats y we use open sources so we can modify code according to our needs.

Comment: It is widely felt that there _is_ something bad about editing them, for the reasons I've already stated.

Comment: Yeah.. but the code i've given is very useful for the developers working on a project under maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code in any controller and you'll get the exact location of function definition :

```
$reflFunc = new ReflectionFunction('function_name');
print $reflFunc->getFileName() . ':' . $reflFunc->getStartLine();
```

it will result something like this :

```
/path/to/php_file.php:linenumber
```